# Export data to csv having datatype ntext SQL server

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis

I want to export data from SQL server to CSV format but having issue with ntext dataype in some tables columns.

data is `ntext` column is html with html tags like br , li etc..

```
BRANDS SUBSECTION:BEAUTY, FRAGRANCE, GROOMING & HEALTH
Acticare
abc def PR
abc def T: 020-0000 1230 e: abc@abc.com

Added Dimension Dentistry
abc def PR
abc def T: 012-3456 7689
```

I have tried export from SQL server direcly exporting to csv format , tried SSIS package,even tried converting to varchar then export but when exported data is not showing correctly.

How do I export data to excel/csv having column data type ntext containing html tags ??

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting the columns in the CSV file destination, try setting the Data Type for the source column to

`text stream [DT_TEXT]` or `Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]` (as the case maybe).

[image]

Comment: I am using script task .. and custom c# code to export all tables to csv..  here is example http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/04/how-to-export-all-tables-to-flat-files.html

Comment: Ok. Are you getting any error? It would help if you add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL Server Export Wizard.
In the choose destination be sure to use a Delimited Format with a double quote text qualifier.

Cast the column in the select statement
CAST([Message] as NVARCHAR(255)) as Message
(Message is defined as ntext)

Use a comma delimiter

...then map to  DT_NTEXT in the export wizard